# GetElementsByTagName Fails to run

Tags: c#

This code fails to run with the following error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in Miner_W.exe
>
> Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

```
    public void obturl()
    {
        string url="http://www.google.com";
        WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser ();
        wb.Navigate (new Uri (url));
        HtmlElementCollection elementcolls = wb.Document.GetElementsByTagName("img");
        foreach (HtmlElement elementcoll in elementcolls)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(elementcoll.GetAttribute("scr"));
        }
        /*string result = elementcoll[i].GetAttribute("src");*/
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to wait until the page has loaded.

```
string url = "http://www.google.com";
WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser();
wb.Navigate(new Uri(url));

wb.DocumentCompleted += (s, e) =>
{
    HtmlElementCollection elementcolls = wb.Document.GetElementsByTagName("img");
    foreach (HtmlElement elementcoll in elementcolls)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(elementcoll.GetAttribute("src"));
    }
};
```

Comment: Awesome! it works. BTW, would you please tell me what is the function of "+,=>" symbol in statement "wb.DocumentCompleted += (s, e) =>"

Comment: @Thomasshi - `+=` - [subscribe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366768.aspx) to event. `=>` - [lambda](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311046.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

There's no scr attribute. I think you meant to put "src" for your GetAttribute method.

Exception happens because for each element you try to get an attribute that doesn't exist on the elements.

Comment: Thanks for help Mikkel, but the code break at this step "HtmlElementCollection elementcolls = wb.Document.GetElementsByTagName("img");"

Comment: Hmm... Is there a way to check if the page has any elements with that tag, before getting them? If so, that might be worth trying

Comment: Yes, i manually go to GOOGLE home page and view the source code and there is "<img height="410" src="/images/nav_logo242.png" width="167" alt="Google" onload="google.aft&&google.aft(this)">"

Comment: I see. Well, then I'm not sure what the problem is. I'm just guessing now, but could it be that your wb.Document is then null? I'm not familiar with what you're using, so I don't know how it operates. Have you tried running the debugger to see the value of wb.Document? Or see what the code does before actually breaking?